# How Does the Darkness Trap Work?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

The tooltip on the Darkness trap seems very vague to me.  The description I found on the DD Wiki is:

> Darkness Trap - When activated, enemies become consumed by darkness, rendering them unable to attack, and making them lose their current target.

I believe that is the actual text from the game, as well.  I'm just confused by what this actually means in gameplay.

For instance, what happens if enemies are in the Darkness trap, but the Huntress is also there?  Will they ignore her and just run straight past her?

What happens if the radius of the Darkness Trap overlaps with a crystal?  Will enemies attacking the crystal stop and just sit around doing nothing?

How about if Squire or Apprentice wall is blocking the enemies from making forward progress.  Will they just stand and wait until Darkness ends, then resume attacking?  Will they try to find another path (or something else to destroy)?

Finally, does the Darkness trap affect ENEMIES, or does it affect the allied structures/units inside the Darkness trap?  For example, if I manually set off a Darkness trap I am standing in, will enemies outside the trap still see me and approach or attack me?  If they enter the trap, will they 'lose me' and stop attacking?  Or, if I am in the trap, will they simply not see me in the first place?

These are all specifics about the Darkness trap that I do not entirely understand; I am more reluctant to spend 5 DU on the trap if I don't fully understand how it works.

Comment: "What happens if the radius of the Darkness Trap overlaps with a crystal? Will enemies attacking the crystal stop and just sit around doing nothing?" this isn't possible as you can't lay traps on top of the crystal, there is a field that prevents you from doing so.  Same with monk auras.

Comment: @yx. So the bigger the radius of your trap, the further from the crystal you have to place it?

Comment: @StrixVaria from what I've observed, yes.  It gets silly on certain maps, like the raining goblins one.  Everything is in so tight together that a monk/huntress with huge radius can't even place a trap anywhere near a spot where it'd be useful.

Comment: @yx While you're right that it cannot have its trigger radius overlap the crystal, if you start it as close as possible on level 0, and upgrade the trap (to 3-stars) the radius does increase, and while it may not completely COVER the crystal, it can TOUCH the crystal.  I am not familiar with the radius of the Darkness trap, but I know it is technically possible with other traps (prox mines, infernos, etc.)  A valid point, because it is not common for traps to be used in this way, but it is technically a possibility.

Comment: I see, I had not though of that possibility.  Very interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my observations from playing with darkness trap for a few rounds:

- All enemies within the darkness trap cannot attack with the following exceptions:

  - Ogres can still attack through it
  - bosses ignore it as well
  - Assassins can jump out of it and attack you
  - It WILL prevent kobolds from detonating for a short while even after they have lit their fuse.  But if you attack them they'll still explode.
- If it happens that you upgrade a trap so it eventually covers the edge of a crystal, enemies will not attack the crystal either because of #1.
- Enemies will just bunch up near the traps and die >:).    The enemies don't seem to try to move and find another path, they'll just cluster there and take constant damage until they die.  Ranged units outside of the path will still attack.

And lastly, it affects any enemies within the cloud.  If you are standing within it, things outside can still shoot at you and see you.

Comment: Awesome, thorough response.  Much appreciated, @yx.

Comment: @Tux after experimenting with it I've started using it more, mixing it up with my defenses.  I've found a darkness trap on top of a squire barricade makes for a truly tough wall that is extremely hard for monsters to get through.  On top of that, you can throw in a gas trap a bit ahead of the wall for good measure.  Its certainly come in handy on the hard and insane halloween challenge.